# Why my string with code is cropped up when I pass it from view to controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity

I have reset password token:

```
 string resetPasswordToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
```

After I go to reset password from email link I pass this token and email to view:

```
  [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult ResetPassword([FromQuery] string token, string email)
    {
        var model = new ResetPasswordViewModel
        {
            Email = email,
            Token = token
        };
        return View(model);
    }
```

The problem is when I trying to pass this token from view to controller, token is cropped before symbol + or " ".
My view:

```
<form 
          method="post" action="reset">
        <input name="Email" type="hidden" value=@Model.Email>
        <input name="Token" type="hidden" value=@Model.Token/>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="NewPassword" class="control-label">New Password</label>
            <input name="NewPassword" class="form-control" />

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label name="ConfirmNewPassword" class="control-label">Confirm New Password</label>
            <input name="ConfirmNewPassword" class="form-control" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
    </form>
```

POST:

```
[HttpPost]
  [Route("reset")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return View(model);

        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
        if (user == null)
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirm");

        var result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(
            user, model.Token, model.NewPassword);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirm");

        foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);

        return View(model);
    }
```

Token:

```
CfDJ8IgVu4V4NxlJoKOV2esH3C3b0PdYklCHqKIB5Qsh0bvnrX4AXaDWgnpJbwCRupsVEKuOYxPctOSe7VqQe+VMzEQna/oNfdB9G3NWxq05wnuLfERKVFiMXMaodDsMV9G6b+J7fJCv8i1QmzR6X/vg/fDNkhmm37m1rJf0TZ41LEiBgthYS9RC/Cg785SaBN0O3VbO+nW/9WRZU1DzIU/ik2/CgkW1gqu9/FszQxVy0GtC
```

Token after cropping:

```
CfDJ8IgVu4V4NxlJoKOV2esH3C3b0PdYklCHqKIB5Qsh0bvnrX4AXaDWgnpJbwCRupsVEKuOYxPctOSe7VqQe
```

Comment: Please update your post to include the HTML generated by the GET (View Source in your browser) as well as the payload submitted to the POST endpoint (from Chrome Developer Tools -> Network tab).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `"` around the attribute values.

This:

```
<input name="Token" type="hidden" value=@Model.Token/>
```

Should be this:

```
<input name="Token" type="hidden" value="@Model.Token"/>
```

However, you should really consider using tag helpers rather than manually creating the attribute value so you don't need to worry about HTML encoding, for example:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Token" />
```

Comment: DavidG, after that, it pass full string but replaced "+" with " "

Comment: See my update (was about to add it but got sidetracked into a meeting)